# Is there only functions based on system calls?

Tags: c, system-calls

When we write code in certain high-level programming language (C/C++, Python, Java) all our functions based on system calls. Is it so? Is there function that does not realize by system calls?

Comment: Of course.  You can write your own functions that don't make any system calls.  There are also many library functions that don't make system calls, such as most math library functions, some string functions (like `strcmp`), etc. etc.

Comment: There are even systems without system calls at all... think of OS-less bare-metal.

Comment: I got it, but I mean that all is based on standard system calls. I don't say about algorithmic functions like strlen(), but all that related to interaction with user anyway concerns system calls.

Comment: If a library function needs to make a system call, it does.  If it doesn't, then it doesn't.  For example, any library function that performs I/O will need to make system calls.  I really can't think of anything else to say about it.  You can usually answer it for yourself:  For a given library function, could you write your own version that doesn't make any system calls (and doesn't call any library functions)?  If the answer is yes, then the library function probably doesn't make any system calls.  If the answer is no, then it probably does.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so at all. The majority of functions you call in those programming languages, or in fact in any programming language, will be in various libraries, and they won’t merely forward to system calls. System calls have to do mostly with blocking synchronization, I/O, thread and process management, and low-level virtual memory management. For example, when you call `malloc`, most of the time it won’t invoke a system call since those are comparatively slow compared to raw C function calls. In fact, most library functions in programming language runtime libraries do their best to avoid system calls. E.g. a mutex will typically attempt to lock using atomic machine instructions and only when that fails will it invoke a system call that blocks the thread.